# Swift 3 : Convert amount value into words

Tags: ios, swift

I’ve a textfield wherein user will enter amount (say 10,000). Once editing is completed amount should be displayed in words (Twenty thousand) in a label.

How can this be done?

Comment: NumberFormatter

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**This code works for me:** Swift 3.2/4:

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()        
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .spellOut

let string = numberFormatter.string(from: 10000)      
print(string)
```

**Output:**

> ten thousand

Comment: Imad - Can you please suggest me how to set the alignment/formatting of code ?